# How to improve data fetching for Postgresql

Tags: pgadmin

I am new to postgresql.

Firstly I have a view called school_view which contains all schools from multiple countries:

```
SELECT * FROM country1_schools
UNION
SELECT * FROM country2_schools
UNION
.....
```

There are around 200,000 records

I try running the following command on pgadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM school_view
```

The results took 17 seconds to return. I try to EXPLAIN ANALYZE the query with

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM school_view
```

The planning time is 15ms and the execution time is 900ms.

So I tried using Materialized View instead of the normal view and

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM school_material_view
```

The planning time becomes 0.192ms and the execution time becomes 36.9ms. However, here comes the problem, when I run

```
SELECT * FROM school_material_view
```

The results STILL take 17 seconds to return. Why is it so? I suspect is the large data fetching and displaying that is causing the problem, but how do I reduce this timing?

Comment: This depends on client and on net speed/latency. You have to say, what client you use. Usually you can do nothing - faster net, faster client. You can reduce number of columns - don't use a star `*` - it can reduce the content moved via network.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem that pgAdmin can take a long time to display a large result set.

Use some other client like `psql`.